# Product of power series as a product of their coefficients

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose that $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j$ and $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k$ have positive radii of convergence $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.  Let $c_n=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jb_{n-j}$ for $n\ge0$; and let $R=\min\{R_1,R_2\}$.

(a) Define $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$. Prove that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ on $(-R,R)$

(b) Give and example where $h$ has a radius of convergence strictly greater than $R$.

Comment: (a) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Proof_of_Mertens.27_theorem

Comment: Not sure that that is quite the same thing, does it hold for power series as well as real series?